# trigger to Update account filed, when a corresponding contact field is updated in salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

How do I create a trigger, to update a field on Account, when the contact, related to this account changes the field.

Example--- If a contact has a mailingcity, the respective Account Mailing city field should updated with the same value

My Trigger is as follows

But its not working
Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to String

The code what i have written is also from google. I am not able to solve this. Please help

```
 trigger ContactToAccountAddress on Contact (after insert,after update) {



List<ID> AccID = New List<ID>();


for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
if(con.MailingCity!=null&& con.AccountId != null){
  AccID.add(con.AccountId);
}
}

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name, BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE id in :AccID];
for(integer i = 0 ; i < accList.size(); i++){
accList[i].BillingStreet =Contact.MailingCity;
}
update accList;
}
```

Comment: To increase your chances of getting the attention of users able to answer this question, you should [edit] it and add the applicable language [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, have you tried to solve this problem yourself? Can you show us some code? Presumably this is in a database - can you show us your DB schema, and expected input and output?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Contact> conlist = [ select mailingCity from Contact where accountId in :AccID];
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name, BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE id in :AccID];
for(integer i = 0 ; i < accList.size(); i++){
   **String address = ''+ conlist[0].get('mailingcity');
accList[i].BillingStreet = address ;
}**
```